# Compute row using a different table

Tags: mysql

I have three tables and I wanted to compute each of the row based on what the rate of the row value is from Table3. For example, I have the following tables:

For Table 1 is where the general data input is done:

Table1

```
|   Day     |   Task        |   Est_Hours   |   Total_Hrs   |   MaxHours    |
|   Monday  |   General     |       8       |       8       |       8       |
|   Tuesday |   Admin       |       5       |       5       |       5       |
```

Table2 is where we do the estimates

Table2

```
|   Task    |   TotalHrs    |
|   General |    8          |
|   Admin   |    5          |
```

And then on the third table is where the rates are for each task on Table2

Table3

```
|   Task    |   Rate    |
|   General |    11.5   |
|   Admin   |    8.50   |
```

I was able to work on this query

```
SELECT t2.Task, 
t1.Est_Hours, 
t1.Total_Hrs, 
t1.MaxHours

FROM Table1 as t1
right JOIN Table2 as t2
ON t1.Task = t2.Task
```

The output of this query is

```
|   Task        |   Est_Hours   |   Total_Hrs   |   MaxHours    |
|   General     |       8       |       8       |       8       |
|   Admin       |       5       |       5       |       5       |
```

I wanted to add another column here for the computation of the hourly rate so that it will look like

```
|   Task        |   Est_Hours   |   Total_Hrs   |   MaxHours    |   Rate    |
|   General     |       8       |       8       |       8       |   92      |
|   Admin       |       5       |       5       |       5       |   42.50   |
```

Wherein the column rate is going to reference the rate from Table3. Hope you guys can help me. Thank you.

Comment: Do another join and multiply `t2.TotalHrs` with `t3.Rate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume Rate column is supposed to be Total_hrs times the Rate?  Then -

```
SELECT t2.Task, 
t1.Est_Hours, 
t1.Total_Hrs, 
t1.MaxHours,
(t1.Total_Hrs * t3.Rate) as Rate
FROM Table1 as t1
JOIN Table2 as t2 ON t1.Task = t2.Task
JOIN Table3 as t3 ON t1.Task = t3.Task
```